# Difficulty in getting DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames to work

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Im trying to convert this storyboard xaml markup into vb code. However when I run the code nothing happens, no exception raised or error just nothing. Is there something im missing?

The storyboard works as expected when run from xaml, however something has gone wrong during my codebehind translation.

Finally I can verify that the target elements that are attached to the storyboard do actually exist.

**XMAL**

```
 <Storyboard x:Name="FlipAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Front">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="90"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Back">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
 Dim firstKf As DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames = New DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
    firstKf.KeyFrames.Add(New EasingDoubleKeyFrame With {.KeyTime = TimeSpan.Zero, .Value = "0"})
    firstKf.KeyFrames.Add(New EasingDoubleKeyFrame With {.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), .Value = "90"})
    Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(firstKf, New PropertyPath(PlaneProjection.RotationYProperty))
    Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTarget(firstKf, front)

    Dim secondKf As DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames = New DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
    secondKf.KeyFrames.Add(New EasingDoubleKeyFrame With {.KeyTime = TimeSpan.Zero, .Value = "-90"})
    secondKf.KeyFrames.Add(New EasingDoubleKeyFrame With {.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), .Value = "-90"})
    secondKf.KeyFrames.Add(New EasingDoubleKeyFrame With {.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400), .Value = "0"})
    Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(secondKf, New PropertyPath(PlaneProjection.RotationYProperty))
    Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTarget(secondKf, back)

    Dim sb = New Media.Animation.Storyboard
    sb.Children.Add(firstKf)
    sb.Children.Add(secondKf)
    sb.Begin()
```

Comment: try to set `duration` to `firstKf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you are binding the incorrect property path on both animations. You want

```
New PropertyPath("Projection.RotationY")
```

or maybe

```
New PropertyPath("(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)")
```

since `front` and `back` don't directly contain the `PlaneProjection.RotationYProperty`.